# How to free or delete an Allocated object in a fuction, from an aspect of c++ (aspectc++)?

Tags: c++, memory-management, aspect

I need a way to *free up* or *delete* allocated memory in a function in a class, from an **aspect** of c++.

Let's Imagine that i have a class called A like this:

```
class A{
Foo* fooObject;

public:
  A() {
    fooObject = new Foo();
  }
}
```

and i must define an aspect like this:

```
aspect FreeMemory{
     advice execution("void A(void)") : after()
     {
          delete fooObject;
     }
};
```

But in FreeMemory aspect, i can't access to *fooObject*. I need a way to solve my problem. Any help?

Answer (score 0):

You can't access to fooObjects cause it's a private member.
You probably have to declare "aspect FreeMemory" into the class (the public part will be right) as "friend".

Comment: if i change the _fooObject_ Property of class _A_ to a public property, then i can access this allocated object from _FreeMemory_ acpect?

Comment: I mean that, in my program i create instances of class A several times and in each construction of this class, my program call my aspect _advice_, In this call i need to delete allocation memory of a specific instance. This is not clear for me yet. I just want to know this way is true or not?